# Why doesn't my find-in-editor input box auto-focus when I open it with my keyboard shortcut?

Tags: visual-studio-code, find, editor

I was wondering if it was possible to automatically select the search bar in VSCode after hitting `ctrl + f` without having to click on it. As shown in the following gif:

[image]

I am aware how this tool is intended to be used, namely: select the word, press `ctrl + f` and find all the other occurnces.

I would still like to know how to do this.

I tried to change settings in `Editor->Find` but none of the combinations I tested had the result I wanted.

Comment: Ctrl+F opens and focuses the FindWidget for me.  It doesn't for you?

Comment: same here. I cannot reproduce your issue. It auto-focuses for me. What if you reinstall VS Code? What platform are you on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was facing this same issue. I found that by adding "Ctrl + F" to another key binding command called "Find With Selection" it solved the problem for me. After adding that key binding the search bar autofocuses when I press "Ctrl + F". Hope this helps

Here are my key bindings. I'm not sure what they all mean so I just left them all and added the last one.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem: I look at my keybindings and `ctrl + f` was used twice, the inference made the issue. Everything works now!

Comment: what was the other keyboard binding? Does this happen for any keybinding? Or only specific ones like the one you had?